# MSCRMFETCH DataProvider does not appear in Visual Studio 2015 in Dynamics CRM 2016 Report

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm

I have a Microsoft CRM Dynamics 2016 report that I am trying to open and run in Visual Studio 2015.  The report opens, but the MSCRMFETCH DataScource type does not load (there is nothing selected in DataSource type dropdown).

I've installed SSDT and CRM BIDS 2016.  What else do I need to install to be able to develop and run reports in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The FetchXML datasource is not there because Visual Studio 2015 is not supported. You will need to use VS2012/2010.

> The following components are required:
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012
>
> -- OR --
>
> Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server Data Tools
>           To install SQL Server Data Tools, on the PC running Visual Studio 2010 go to the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express download page, download the following files appropriate to your CPU architecture and language:
>               ENU\x64\SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe
>               ENU\x86\SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU.exe
>           Select the "SSDT" or "SQL Server Data Tools" installation

[More information](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50375)